# decimal precision

Tags: bash, python

I have a variable a=1.349804687500000093e-02. I want to have a in 5 digit precision. I tried to use the following command which prints the variable as I want but does not save it.

```
a=1.349804687500000093e-02
b= | python -c "print round($a, 7)"
### result
0.0135
#### it does not give anything when print b
echo $b

######
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for a high-level language like python here: the bash shell's built-in `printf` can do decimal format conversions

```
$ a=1.349804687500000093e-02
$ printf -v b '%.5f\n' $a
$ echo $b
0.01350
```

If you *did* want to use a python command, the syntax you'd need is *command substitution* `$(command)`:

```
$ b=$(python -c "print round($a,7)")
$ echo $b
0.013498
```

Comment: Can you add illustration on using bc

Comment: @OmarAli actually I was mistaken - I don't think it can (easily) be done with `bc` since it doesn't appear to accept inputs in scientific notation

Comment: yes i just discovered that printf -v b '%.5f\n' $a does not accept the number

Comment: also, when I add the python command in .bsh file. it give error. example is below:
#!/bin/bash
# My first script
b=$(python -c "print round($a,7)")
echo $b

##Result

    print round(,7)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @OmarAli I'm confused: **both** of those should work. How exactly are you executing them?

Comment: @OmarAli it looks like `$a` is empty in your example: you need to assign `a=1.349804687500000093e-02` first

Comment: yes, it works now. remove your first answer because it does not work and keep the second to vote for you.